# Upload Metadata into Salesforce from GitHub

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-object, metadata-api, metadata, sandbox

There is a GitHub repository with metadata such as tabs, custom objects with fields, apps, etc.

What is the best approach to upload that metadata from GitHub into the SF Sandbox org?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. This question was downvoted because you haven't shown any research let alone define what metadata is already in the sandbox. Please use [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Fawcett's [Deploy to Salesforce](https://github.com/afawcett/githubsfdeploy) does exactly that. It's not the only option, but certainly one of the easiest. Other than that, for any arbitrary repo, just clone the repo locally, then use the SF CLI to deploy the metadata.

Comment: or, you could use a vendor devops tool to deploy from VCS to org, choosing items to deploy and seeing their diffs